# Query to filter by alphabetic order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

template.html is

```
{% for field in types%}
 {{field}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to sort out the list in alphabetic order.Used this `type_list = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=True).order_by('title')` in above view to sort.I don't know whether i queried right.It is not giving any error,but function is not happening.Need help.

Thanks

Comment: Is the view you posted `incident.views.incident_types`? Why are redirecting directly after you `filter` your queryset?

Comment: no,view posted is for type_list,sorry,after filter it should redirect to type_list.html.But i did the changes,still not working

Comment: When you redirect you are creating an entirely new request (i.e. a redirect response goes back to the user telling them to make a new request to the address specified in the redirect response) so the code beforehand is redundant.

Comment: so,where should i query this.More thing is this is a child list of incident_types view.Please refer my model and suggest me

Comment: yes,i changed the template{{field}} to {{field.title}} the values are not rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to order alphabetically the form's choices, you will have to modify the query where you get them, inside the form, not in the views, so modify the line in the `__init__` method of the form like this:

```
def __init__(self, type_id, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    type = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type_id).order_by('title')
    MY_CHOICES=((type.id, type.title) for type in type)
    _type_checkbox.choices = MY_CHOICES
    ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped me in solving another problem.I upvoted your answer,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to sort when rendering the template, then I prefer the simplicity of [dictsort](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort).

```
{% for field in types|dictsort:"title" %}
 {{field}}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Be aware that it has some weird behavior around capitalization. I think it prioritizes capitalized words over uncapitalized words instead of functioning in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: This does not work at all...